# n-dimensional matrix (tensor) permutation notation

Tags: matrices, notation, permutations, matlab, tensors

I am looking for a mathematical notation for MATLAB's **permute** function

> permute(A,order) rearranges the dimensions of A so that they are in
>   the order specified by the vector order. B has the same values of A
>   but the order of the subscripts needed to access any particular
>   element is rearranged as specified by order. All the elements of order
>   must be unique, real, positive, integer values.

If I am not mistaken, it is just a permutation of an n-order tensor. Is there a recommended notation for such an operation?

Note: The function does not permute columns of the matrix. It only permutes its dimensions.

In case of a 2D matrix there are only two possibilities:

1. permute($A_{m \times n}$, [1, 2]) = $A_{m \times n}$
2. permute($A_{m \times n}$, [2, 1]) = $A_{n \times m}$.

In case of a 3D matrix there are 6 permutations.

1. permute($A_{m \times n \times o}$, [1, 2, 3]) = $A_{m \times n \times o}$
2. permute($A_{m \times n \times o}$, [1, 3, 2]) = $A_{m \times o \times n}$
3. permute($A_{m \times n \times o}$, [2, 1, 3]) = $A_{n \times m \times o}$
4. ... and so on

Comment: I don't know. I am also curious about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my private notes, I have written $A^\sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the permutation in cycle notation. Example:
$$R+R^{(2,3,4)}+R^{(4,3,2)}=0$$
Common transpositions would then look like $A^\top=A^{(1,2)}$.

But that's not perfect: One would want $(A^\sigma)^\tau = A^{(\sigma\tau)}$, but with the usual right-to-left composition rule the above would be $(A^\sigma)^\tau = A^{(\tau\sigma)}$.

A better option would then be to write $\sideset{^\sigma}{}{\!A}$ instead;
then $\sideset{^\tau}{}{\left(\sideset{^\sigma}{}{\!A}\right)} = \sideset{^{(\tau\sigma)}}{}{\!A}$. But that looks exotic.

Another aspect: I often find expressions with slot-permuted tensors easier to understand when given the *inverse* permutation. Because those expressions typically do something with the leftmost or rightmost slots (e.g. contractions with adjacent tensor expressions), and I need to know which slots of the original $A$ have ended up there. That's basically an inverse lookup.

This leads to the following proposal: Write $A^{\bar{\sigma}}$ where $\bar{\sigma}$ is the *inverse* of the slots permutation. Literally known $\bar{\sigma}$ can be given in cycle notation. Note that $\bar{\sigma}$ maps $1$ to the slot number in the original $A$ that is leftmost after the permutation. Transpositions like $(1,2)$ are their own inverses, so the inversion is not an issue for those.
This notation fulfills $(A^{\bar{\sigma}})^{\bar{\tau}} = A^{(\bar{\sigma}\bar{\tau})}$ with the usual right-to-left composition rule.

Note that the vector literal in your example lists the values $[\bar{\sigma}(1),\bar{\sigma}(2),\ldots]$. Thus your MATLAB snippet already uses the inverse permutation, and this proposal would just express that in cycle notation.

Whatever you decide to do, better *declare it explicitly*. As you can see from the above, the most suitable notation might not be the most intuitive one.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and that we want to permute the columns. Then we need a bijection $\sigma$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and we can define $f:M_{m\times n}\rightarrow M_{m\times n}$ as 
$$
f([m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n]) = [m_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\ldots,m_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}].
$$

Comment: The function does not permute columns of the matrix. It only permutes its dimensions.